# Invalid Firebase Database path

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a application that stores data into firebase and retrieves it

I am receiving a error while fetching(receiving) data from firebase using a firebase recycler adapter

the error

```html
                                                                                         

    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase 
 Database path: 
{UserName=Mohit,VideoPath=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodyyoucantstayhungry.appspot.com/o/Video_Upload%2FStreet%2F12%20Apr%2F08%3A48%20AM%2Fvideo%3A35373.mp4?alt=media&token=9192cfb8-cf5e-4585-998f-8f86eb802372, Short_Desc=jgatajy, DateTime=12 Apr 08t48 AM, VideoName=jrHrngnTu, Long_Desc=iysyisuoo, Views=0, Likes=0}. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zf.zzhb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
at com.foodies.mohitgupta.foodyyoucantstsyhungry.MainArea$2.onChildAdded(MainArea.java:200)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.px.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
```

**The Firebase Structure**

```html
Video_Upload
            Street
                  12 Apr 08:48 AM
                                DateTime:value
                                likes:value
                                Long_Desc:value
                                Short_desc:value
                                UserName:value
                                VideoName:value
                                VideoPath:value
                                Views:values
```

**I am recieving this error in following code MainArea.java**

```html
  

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final DatabaseReference[] StreetRef1 = new DatabaseReference[1];
        StreetRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Video_Upload").child("Street");
        StreetRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s ) {

                String Date=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                StreetRef1[0] =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Video_Upload").child("Street").child(Date);
                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<StreetDataFetcher,StreetRecycler> FBRA=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<StreetDataFetcher, StreetRecycler>(
                        StreetDataFetcher.class,
                        R.layout.card_recycler_view,
                        StreetRecycler.class,
                        StreetRef1[0]

                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder( StreetRecycler viewHolder, StreetDataFetcher model, int position ) {

                        viewHolder.setUserName(model.getUserName());
                        viewHolder.setDateTime(model.getDateTime());
                        viewHolder.setVideoName(model.getVideoName());
                        viewHolder.setShort_Desc(model.getShort_Desc());
                    }
                };
                StreetRecyclerView.setAdapter(FBRA);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s ) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot ) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s ) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError ) {

            }
        });

    }
```

```
**the View Holder class i the following code is**


**StreetRecycler.class**
```

```html
 /**
     * Recycler View Holder
     */
    public static class StreetRecycler extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;
        TextView UsernameText,date,VideoName,Title,ShortDescription;
        public StreetRecycler( View itemView ) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
        }

        public void setUserName( String userName )
        {
            UsernameText=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.UsernameText);
            UsernameText.setText(userName);
        }

        public void setDateTime( String dateTime )
        {
            date=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            date.setText(dateTime);
        }
        public void setVideoName( String videoName )
        {
            Title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
            Title.setText(videoName);
        }
        public void setShort_Desc( String short_Desc )
        {
            ShortDescription=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.ShortDescription);
            ShortDescription.setText(short_Desc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: because of this `Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply as per error message**

I think you Firebase DataBase name has some spacial character.

**Or** i think you need to use the DB name in your code as.

```
.getReference(FIRE_DB_NAME);
```

in this line.

```
StreetRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Video_Upload").child("Street");
```

Comment: it worked but data is still not fetching from database

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'